# How to parse json containg index number for an object in go lang

Tags: json, go

below is the json string

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type XYZ struct {
    //ParamName  string
    Value      string
    Values     []string
    Parameters map[string]XYZ
}

type Service struct {
    Parameters map[string]XYZ
}

func main() {
    jsont := []byte(`{"Parameters": {"ManagedElement":{"0":{"Parameters": {"Id": {"Value": "MEId1"},"GNBCUCPFunction": {"Parameters": {"Id": {"Value": "GNBCUCPId1"},"EP_NgC":{"Parameters": {"Id": {"Value": "EPNGCId1"},"attributes": {"Parameters": {"remoteAddress": {"Value": "0.0.0.0"},"localAddress": {"Parameters": {
    "ipAddress": {"Value": "0.0.0.0"},"vlanId": {"Value": "1"}}}}}}}}}}},"1":{"Parameters": {"Id": {"Value": "MEId1"},"GNBCUCPFunction": {"Parameters": {"Id": {"Value": "GNBCUCPId1"},"EP_NgC":{"Parameters": {"Id": {"Value": "EPNGCId1"},"attributes": {"Parameters": {"remoteAddress": {"Value": "0.0.0.0"},"localAddress": {"Parameters": {
    "ipAddress": {"Value": "0.0.0.0"},"vlanId": {"Value": "1"}}}}}}}}}}}}}}`)

    var jsonb Service
    json.Unmarshal(jsont, &jsonb)
    fmt.Println("\nReceived Body :", jsonb)
}
```

output : Received Body : {map[ManagedElement:{ [] map[]}]}

I am expecting go program example to parse above json

How we can parse the json which contains the index number?

If I remove the index and provide array of object everything worked fine. But the requirement is need to parse json with indexed object.

Comment: Use the `encoding/json` package. Plenty of examples here on SO and all over the web.

Comment: Yes I am using the same. But not able to find any way to parse if it has index like "0", "1". Any thought on this?

Comment: *"not able to find any way to parse if it has index like "0", "1""* -- It's unclear what you're trying to say or do. The `encoding/json` package works fine regardless of whether an object's key is `"0"` or `"1"`. Update the question by properly describing the problem you're facing. By adding your Go code that you've written in an attempt to solve the problem. Include the desired output and the actual output. We can't read your mind.

Comment: I have provided the details what I am trying. Please suggest. Thanks

Comment: Given the full code

Comment: The `Service`'s field should be `Parameters map[string]map[string]XYZ` (a map of maps). Or `Parameters struct { ManagedElement map[string]XYZ }`. Your choice. You can also use a tool like https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/ to get a better idea of the struct compatible with the target json. Here's an example of an auto generated struct with modifications: https://go.dev/play/p/P9H5W9k17Yx

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `interface{}` type in case of complex JSON, it can be used to parse JSON into data structure of any type. In your example you can use map of interfaces : `map[string]interface{}` along with `json.Unmarshal` function from `encoding/json` package to decode JSON.

```
func parseJSON(jsonStr string) (map[string]interface{}, error) {
    var data map[string]interface{}
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jsonStr), &data)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return data, nil
}
```

Comment: Yes I am able to parse it using map[string]interface{}. But wanted to fit in some sort of struct. Any thaught?

Comment: So define your struct types manually and replace `map[string]interface{}` with your custom struct in the above function. PS. You should edit your question to include info what you have tried, and more details what you expect to make it less vague.

Comment: Provided the details what I am trying to do. Please suggest

Comment: Given full code